# Laravel store files with permissions 774

Tags: laravel, permissions, storage, store

Im loosing mind. I upload files via laravel API, they are stored in folder and file always get permission `644`, is there any way how to store files as `775` ?

can i somehow add this to my function ?

```
 (0755, true, true)
```

function for store files:

```
 $result=$request->file('file_path')->store('apiFiles/'.$idParameter);
```

thanks for any help

Comment: its recommended files to be 644/664 and folder 755/775

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change permission of file after creating them by [chmod](https://www.php.net/function.chmod) command like this:

```
$result=$request->file('file_path')->store('apiFiles/'.$idParameter);
chmod('file path',0775);
```

Answer (score 5):

In laravel you can use `'public'` or `'private'` disks and set the permissions options in the config file `filesystems.php`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#permissions

The public visibility translates to `0755` for directories and `0644` for files. You can modify the permissions mappings in your filesystems configuration file:

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'permissions' => [
        'file' => [
            'public' => 0664,
            'private' => 0600,
        ],
        'dir' => [
            'public' => 0775,
            'private' => 0700,
        ],
    ],
],
```

You can then store files with specific visibility like it suggests here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-visibility

Or you can use the built in php function `chmod()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: Such a nice thorough answer !!!